# Printing a text file in a patteren

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I have a very large amount of text(100000 words)  to parse and it has got following format

```
abrasion abrade:stem<>ion:suffix
abstainer abstain:stem<>er:suffix
abstention abstain:stem<>ion:suffix
accessibility access:stem<>ible:suffix<>ity:suffix
accretion accrete:stem<>ion:suffix
activist active:stem<>ist:suffix
adaptable adapt:stem<>able:suffix
addiction addict:stem<>ion:suffix
```

I need to convert it to this format

```
abrasion (S (abrade:stem) (ion:suffix))
abstainer (S (abstain:stem) (er:suffix))
abstention (S (abstain:stem) (ion:suffix))
accessibility (S (S (access:stem) (ible:suffix)) ity:suffix))
accretion (S (accrete:stem) (ion:suffix))
activist (S (active:stem) ist:suffix))
adaptable (S (adapt:stem) able:suffix))
addiction (S (addict:stem) ion:suffix))
```

The awk code, I use is

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\n"}{
   a=gensub(/([a-zA-Z]*):stem/,"( S\\1:stem)", "g");
   while ( a ~ /stem)<>.*:suffix/) {
     a=gensub(/(\([a-zA-Z]*:stem\).*?)<>([a-zA-Z]*):suffix/,"(\\1\\2:suffix)", "g", a);
   }
   while ( a ~ /<>/) {
     a=gensub(/([a-zA-Z]*?:prefix)<>(.*)/,"(S\\1\\2)", "g", a);
   }
   print a;}
```

This code fails to produce desired output and produce results for only 5 tokens.

Comment: `accessibility (S (S (access:stem) (ible:stem)) ity:suffix))` is incorrect, it should be `accessibility (S (S (access:stem) (ible:suffix) (ity:suffix))`, I think. The last three lines as well.

Comment: @syck. This is the format of data set

Comment: Yes, but above you have suffix and below you have stem, and the last three lines do not have parens round the suffixes... what is the reason for?

Comment: The parentheses for accessibility also do not match.

Comment: @syck I don't know. why it is like that. I am interested in presenting data in prescribed form. I have around 10000 pairs

Comment: @Karun: The problems we have are with your required output that you have labelled *I need to convert it to this format*. Presumably you have written it yourself? Have you made a mistake with the last three lines, where the suffixes have a closing parenthesis but no opening one? For example, `abrasion` has `(ion:suffix)` whereas `addiction` has `ion:suffix)`

Comment: Interesting thing that OP posted an almost identical question yesterday that already has an accepted and upvoted answer and contains more information on the topic than here, reposting here the code from that answer  and claiming it does not work. This is what I call wasting my time and I do not like it.

Comment: @syck. The funny fact is that no one really read the post and decided to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: borodin did. But it did not look like a question that has been asked here before, so noone did search for that. It would have been fair to give a link to the previous question and to give the additional information that you provided there. Even more as the example you provided here is not valid in the clause structure notation documented in the linked PDF document.

Comment: @syck. I took the code that was already there and I stated the problem.  The problem was  different because I tried to work with the code.  I just asked about the  problem of the code.  "This code fails to produce desired output and produce results for only 5 tokens."  in the last line. Yeah, It is true that I did not link the old question. My mistake! And I accept it. This is not a justification.

Answer (score 1):

Have look at [this](https://eval.in/540393):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# provide data
$t = <<'EOT';
abrasion abrade:stem<>ion:suffix
abstainer abstain:stem<>er:suffix
abstention abstain:stem<>ion:suffix
accessibility access:stem<>ible:suffix<>ity:suffix
accretion accrete:stem<>ion:suffix
activist active:stem<>ist:suffix
adaptable adapt:stem<>able:suffix
addiction addict:stem<>ion:suffix
EOT

# iterate over lines
foreach $line (split /\n/, $t) {

    # split the line
    ($word, $def) = split /\s+/, $line, 2;
    @parts = split /\<\>/, $def;

    # loop over attributes
    $new = '';
    for ($pos = 0; $pos<$#parts; $pos++) {
            $new = 
                $new eq '' ?
                qq[(S ($parts[0]) ($parts[1]))] :  # create new entry
                qq[(S $new ($parts[$pos]))];       # encapsulate existing entry
    }

    # output
    print qq($word $new\n);
}
```

produces:

```
abrasion (S (abrade:stem) (ion:suffix))
abstainer (S (abstain:stem) (er:suffix))
abstention (S (abstain:stem) (ion:suffix))
accessibility (S (S (access:stem) (ible:suffix)) (ible:suffix))
accretion (S (accrete:stem) (ion:suffix))
activist (S (active:stem) (ist:suffix))
adaptable (S (adapt:stem) (able:suffix))
addiction (S (addict:stem) (ion:suffix))
```

Possibly the groupings at accessibility should be the other way round, but this is not proofable for me, because your example seems to be syntactically incorrect there.

If this is the case, you would have to loop from `$#parts-1`to `0` instead.

Or possibly all stems and all suffices should be grouped into an `S()` group seperately.

Answer (score 1):

```
use v5.10;
use strict;

while( my $line = <>)
{
    chomp $line;
    if( $line =~ /^(\w+)\s+(.+)/)
    {
        my $word = $1;
        my @stems = split '<>', $2;

        if( @stems )
        {
            my $stems = sprintf '(%s)', shift @stems;
            while( @stems )
            {
                $stems = sprintf '(S %s (%s))', $stems, shift @stems;
            }
            say "$word $stems";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the example seems to be not correct I try to give an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution:

```
cat >infile.txt <<TXT
abrasion abrade:stem<>ion:suffix
abstainer abstain:stem<>er:suffix
abstention abstain:stem<>ion:suffix
accessibility access:stem<>ible:suffix<>ity:suffix
accretion accrete:stem<>ion:suffix
activist active:stem<>ist:suffix
adaptable adapt:stem<>able:suffix
addiction addict:stem<>ion:suffix
TXT

awk '
function proc(desc,    p1, p2) { 
  if (match(desc, /^.*<>/, arr)) {
    p1 = substr(desc, 1, RLENGTH - 2);
    p2 = substr(desc, RLENGTH + 1);
    return "S (" proc(p1) ") ("p2")";
  } 

  return desc;
}

{
  print $1, "(" proc($2) ")"
}
' infile.txt
```

Output:

```
abrasion (S (abrade:stem) (ion:suffix))
abstainer (S (abstain:stem) (er:suffix))
abstention (S (abstain:stem) (ion:suffix))
accessibility (S (S (access:stem) (ible:suffix)) (ity:suffix))
accretion (S (accrete:stem) (ion:suffix))
activist (S (active:stem) (ist:suffix))
adaptable (S (adapt:stem) (able:suffix))
addiction (S (addict:stem) (ion:suffix))
```

The code calls the recursive function `proc` for the second field. It finds the last occurence of '<>' and then formats the string calling itself again for the first part. That's it. The only trick is to add the local p1 and p2 variables to the argument list of `proc` to make them really local.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible `awk` solution:

```
{
    a = gensub(/([a-zA-Z]*:stem)<>([a-zA-Z]*:suffix)/,"(S (\\1) (\\2))", "1")
    while ( a ~ /<>[a-zA-Z]*:suffix/) {
        a = gensub(/(\(S.*)<>([a-zA-Z]*:suffix)/,"(S \\1 (\\2))", "1", a)
    }
    print a
}
```

Output:

```
abrasion (S (abrade:stem) (ion:suffix))
abstainer (S (abstain:stem) (er:suffix))
abstention (S (abstain:stem) (ion:suffix))
accessibility (S (S (access:stem) (ible:suffix)) (ity:suffix))
accretion (S (accrete:stem) (ion:suffix))
activist (S (active:stem) (ist:suffix))
adaptable (S (adapt:stem) (able:suffix))
addiction (S (addict:stem) (ion:suffix))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this Perl program will do what you need

The data sample is really too short, and you have given no explanation for the mismatched parentheses in your desired output for `activist`, `adaptable` and `addiction`, but I have programmed the pattern that I can see

I trust you are able to open a file in Perl? If you supply the path to your input file as a parameter on the command line then all you need to do is change `<DATA>` to `<>` and it will work. The output is sent to STDOUT, so if you want to store it to a file then simply redirect the output on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ($word, $ss) = split;
    my @ss = split /<>/, $ss;

    while ( @ss > 1 ) {
        my $s = sprintf 'S (%s) (%s)', @ss[0,1];
        splice @ss, 0, 2, $s;
    }

    printf "%s (%s)\n", $word, $ss[0];
}


__DATA__
abrasion abrade:stem<>ion:suffix
abstainer abstain:stem<>er:suffix
abstention abstain:stem<>ion:suffix
accessibility access:stem<>ible:suffix<>ity:suffix
accretion accrete:stem<>ion:suffix
activist active:stem<>ist:suffix
adaptable adapt:stem<>able:suffix
addiction addict:stem<>ion:suffix
```

#### output

```
abrasion (S (abrade:stem) (ion:suffix))
abstainer (S (abstain:stem) (er:suffix))
abstention (S (abstain:stem) (ion:suffix))
accessibility (S (S (access:stem) (ible:suffix)) (ity:suffix))
accretion (S (accrete:stem) (ion:suffix))
activist (S (active:stem) (ist:suffix))
adaptable (S (adapt:stem) (able:suffix))
addiction (S (addict:stem) (ion:suffix))
```